# Start activity from another without loading the first's layout

Tags: android, android-activity, layout

My launcher activity may start another on a certain condition, it looks something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    prefManager = new PreferenceManager();
    if (prefManager.startMain(this)) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
        return;
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wizard);
...
...
```

`PreferenceManager` is just a helper for easy access to `SharedPreferneces`.

If the condition is true, a flashing of the first activity layout is shown and only then the second activity starts.

I want to skip the flashing of the first activity layout when starting the second (I actually expected this since I don't call `setContentView` but apparently, it isn't).

I thought about creating a 3rd, transparent layout activity which starts the correct activity but I hope there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the startActivity() and finish() around so finish() is called first, haven’t been able to test but could be

```
if (prefManager.startMain(this)) {
        finish()
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
```

Shouldn’t be a need to call return either

Comment: Since it's all happens in `onCreate()` and `finish()` calls `onDestroy()` I find it dangerous to switch the two.